# Missing quiz description in Canvas

Tags: r-exams

I've successfully imported a quiz into canvas, but for some reason the description does not appear (even though it's in the XML).

[image]

(this box is empty when I import the quiz generated by the command below).

Other question, maybe related – the imported quiz appears under "Assignment quizzes", but I would prefer it under "Practice quizzes". Can this be changed via exams?

```
exams2canvas(c("swisscapital.Rmd"), 
             stitle = c("Section 1", "Section 2"), 
             adescription = "This short quiz is for us (the lecturers) to get a sense of where the maths skills of the cohort are at.",
             sdescription = "Vector of descriptions for each section, omitted if empty",
             name = "Preliminary Maths Skills Assessment", 
             converter =  "pandoc-mathml")
```

Comment: I can confirm this. I guess that different QTI elements are used for storing the descriptions on different learning management systems. Maybe you can try the following: Create a quiz with the desired descriptions in the Canvas editor and then export it to QTI 1.2. And then you can compare the QTI elements that are used for the comments by Canvas and those that are used by R/exams. Then you could see the difference and we could change `exams2canvas()` correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take another look (at first glance I didn't see an obvious difference last time I compared the two). As for the type, it appears to be hard-coded as `Assignment quizzes` in exams, it'd be nice to have the option to select another type such as `Practice quizzes`

Comment: I played around with the `<quiz_type>` tag. Even when I set `<quiz_type>practice_quiz</quiz_type>` the tests are still imported as `assignment`, I'm not sure why. I also changed the type in Canvas, exported and re-imported the quiz and then it worked correctly. I couldn't see obvious differences in any of the zipped XML files, though. Same with the `<description>`. If you have any more insights about these, these would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped – I tried to diff the files and after several import/export attempts I can't seem to find the thing that makes Canvas ignore the description or the quiz type :/

Comment: It's good not be alone! I have exactly the same experience playing around with the `<quiz_type>`. With the new R/exams 2.4-1 from R-Forge you can do now `exams2canvas(..., quiztype = "practice_quiz")`. This also ends up in the XML but I have no idea why it is ignored by Canvas. If you want to try it also you can run `install.packages("exams", repos = "https://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. Does your university have any support for Canvas? If so, you might try asking them if they know why `<description>` and `<quiz_type>` are ignored in our files.

Comment: We have recently switched to Canvas, yes, but it doesn't look like we have much technical support for this kind of thing – it's probably not a local setting but something buit-in Canvas importer (and it does work, for the files exported from Canvas, somehow, so it must be a syntax glitch). I wonder if the community forums at https://community.canvaslms.com might have an answer? I'll try posting later

Comment: Thanks, please keep me posted. My former colleagues at WU Vienna also switched to Canvas recently and I'll try to find out whether they have some support for this. And, yes, I agree that there must be something in the XML that is not right but I couldn't find any description of this in the Canvas docs.

Comment: Will do – [the post is here](https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Canvas-Developers-Group/Importing-Quiz-from-QTI-generated-programmatically-glitch-with/m-p/562857/highlight/true#M8982)

Comment: Someone responded that they diagnosed the problem to be in the questions file, suggesting that replacing that file with one from Canvas brings the quiz_type and description back. I haven't managed to reproduce this on my first attempt though.